# Piecing together Django views

Tags: python, django

Is it good practice to treat individual app views as a blocks of HTML that can be pieced together to form a larger site? If not, what is the best way to reuse app views from project to project, assuming each one uses a different set of templates?

Answer (score 2):

A general good practice to define views with a `template_name` kwarg. This allows a the default template to be overridden. This is common in generic views.

```
#my reusable view
def list_items(request, template_name="items.html"):
  items=Item.objects.all()
  return render_to_response(template_name,
    {'items': items},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))

#some other view
from my.reusable.views import list_items

def list_special(request, template_name="spectial_items.html"):
  return list_items(request, template_name=template_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little too generic.

The general way of doing it involves:

- Extend templates of the reusable apps
- Pass the new template name to the view (Reusable apps should accepts that argument)
- Also pass `extra_context` to the reusable-generic-view
- Use your own view to create an `extra_context` and return the reuse-able view, from your view.

Answer (score 0):

usually each application should provide views for the basic functionality - where the application takes full control over the user and the page.

functionality which can be displayed in the basic page layout (e.g. 'last 5 posts in my blog') would be a perfect use case for template tags - i usually use simple [inclusion tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags). so you wouldn't combine multiple views into one template, but always have one view which handles the request, and everything around can be aggregated using template tags.